# How to exclude items with identical field if the datefield is bigger than in others duplicates?

Tags: django, django-models

So I have a Comments model and by querying

`comments = Comments.objects.values('students_id', 'created_at')`

I get this output

```
<QuerySet [
{'students_id': 4, 'created_at': datetime.date(2019, 6, 19)}, {'students_id': 2, 'created_at': datetime.date(2019, 6, 3)}, {'students_id': 1, 'created_at': datetime.date(2019, 6, 24)}, {'students_id': 6, 'created_at': datetime.date(2019, 6, 4)}, {'students_id': 6, 'created_at': datetime.date(2019, 6, 19)}, {'students_id': 5, 'created_at': datetime.date(2019, 6, 5)}, {'students_id': 4, 'created_at': datetime.date(2019, 7, 28)}, {'students_id': 6, 'created_at': datetime.date(2019, 6, 11)}]>
```

It's three comments by student with id=6 and two comments by student with id=4. 
What I need to get is only one *latest* comment from every student. In this example it'll look like this:

```
<QuerySet [
{'students_id': 2, 'created_at': datetime.date(2019, 6, 3)}, {'students_id': 1, 'created_at': datetime.date(2019, 6, 24)}, {'students_id': 6, 'created_at': datetime.date(2019, 6, 19)}, {'students_id': 5, 'created_at': datetime.date(2019, 6, 5)}, {'students_id': 4, 'created_at': datetime.date(2019, 7, 28)},]>
```

Thanks in advance for the answer!

Comment: Do you actually want to delete the other comments from the database, or just exclude them from the queryset?

Comment: Exclude them from the queryset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use annotate and max to get desired result like this `Comments.objects.values('students_id').annotate(Max('created_at'))`
and the output will be like this `<QuerySet [
{'students_id': 2, 'created_at__max': datetime.date(2019, 6, 3)}, {'students_id': 1, 'created_at__max': datetime.date(2019, 6, 24)},]>` which will have students_id and latest created_at. To use this you have to import Max from django.db.models like this `from django.db.models import Max`

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
queryset=Comments.objects.values('students_id', 'created_at').group_by('students_id').annotate(Latest_created_at=Max('created_at'))
queryset.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

In raw SQL it would be `... WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Comments cc WHERE cc.student_id = c.student_id AND cc.created_at > c.created_at)`

```
later_comments = Comments.objects.filter(student_id=OuterRef('student_id'), 
    created_at__gt=OuterRef('created_at'), ).values('created_at', )

latest_comments = Comments.objects.\
    annotate(has_later_comments=Exists(later_comments), ).\
    filter(has_later_comments=False, )
```

If your `created_at` is a `Date` column (no time), then you need to use `=>` instead of `>` because perhaps more than one comment can be created during a day. So the query would contain additional predicate with extra column for ordering comments (like id): `WHERE cc.created_at > c.created_at OR cc.created_at = c.created_at AND cc.id > c.id`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries